# Trouble with the javafx 8 sample 3D application

Tags: actionlistener, javafx-8

Since the release of javafx 8 is coming up right around the corner, I figured now would be a good time to get better acquainted with a few of the new features. First on my list: enhanced (true) 3D shapes and rendering! Working for an engineering company, being able to integrate a rich 3d environment into some of our visualizations will be great!

In any case, I was working through the 'getting started' [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/jfxpub-3d_graphics.htm) and all was well. Able to compile everything, getting familiar with how they structure all of their layouts in 3d, etc. etc. It was great! After familiarizing myself with some of the more advanced translations, I decided to take a look at their final 'sample 3d application' that had things like mouse and keyboard listeners to set the angle and orientation of the camera, which was the only thing I hadn't done yet. (you can find a link to the source code I downloaded for it, complete with a nbproject [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/sampleapp.htm#CJAHFAF) It's called MoleculeSampleApp.zip and it's in the top right corner of the page).

So I go to compile it, everything shows up just fine, the molecule, the axis, and then I try to initiate any action at all, a mouse click, drag, a recognized keyboard input, etc. Everything on the scene **simply vanishes**.

Well that's strange, I think to myself, so I take a look at the code. Everything looks to be in order, and a few print lines later, I find out that the contents of the graph aren't disappearing until the very END of the listener, whenever that happens to be. Nothing inside of the listener is actually causing the disappearing (unless of course it's the hide/show keyboard shortcuts).

To be honest, I'm a bit baffled by this. There are no exceptions being thrown, no errors printing out. It just disappears, and that's the end of it.

If anyone has any idea why this is happening I would be immensely grateful. It's worth noting, I'm using the javafx 8 developer preview b132.

(if you would like me to post the entire source here, let me know, it's only about 600 lines altogether, but that's pretty heavy for a SO question so I'm just going to leave the links for now).

**tl;dr**

The moleculesimpleapp.zip located [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/sampleapp.htm#CJAHFAF) makes everything disappear on any action it knows to listen for, with no clear reason, why?

-Will

Comment: I just tested the zip and it works fine in 8b127 on XP3, running in Netbeans 7.4

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if it's a b132 bug, I'll try re-compiling with 127 to attempt to isolate the error, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. It doesn't seem like the b127 made any difference for me, not working on Win7 64 bit, netbeans 7.4